Rails Turbo Frames: "Content missing" after Update-action (View doesn't update)
I like to use Turbo Frames in my existing Rails-App.
index.view looks now this way:


<h1>Projects List</h1>
<div><strong><%= pluralize(@projects.size, "Project") %> currently</strong></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= link_to project.title, project %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= project.description.truncate(40) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to "Show", project, class: "link-info" %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= turbo_frame_tag "edit_curr_project" do %>
          <div>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_project_path(project), class: "link-warning" %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>





<turbo-frame id="edit_curr_project">
  <h1>Edit Project</h1>
  <%= render "form", project: @project %>
</turbo-frame>



The Controller-class:


class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Project created successfully"
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Project updated successfully"
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Project has become removed"
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description)
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end
end



Form (before update):

Error-message afterward:

It works in so far, that the entity gots updated. But "Content missing" in shown in the index-view and I need a browser-reload to see the recent update?
What I'm doing wrong?
How can this be fixed, so that the view updates?

After update you are redirecting to the show view. But it seems for every project you iterate through @projects.each do |project| there is no project specific turbo frame in your code. Ho do you handle the single project show view ? What is the view attached to the show action of your controller ?

@Maxence Thanks for your comment. I have now added the complete Controller-class.

The problem is not really in your controller but rather in your views. Your index view, instead of displaying the content of each project (what is inside the iteration <% @projects.each do |project| %>) should rather render the partial _project.html.erb. And in this partial you should add a unique turbo frame specific to your project. then when you render the project in your show view, the project you have updated is replaced completely.

You should use partials when implementing Turbo frames because it looks for same ID of frame when you click a link or submit a form inside a turbo frame. For example,
_comment.html.erb partial
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment) do %>
  <div class="rounded-lg shadow-sm p-4 mb-4">
    <div class="flex items-start">
      <% if comment.user.avatar.attached? %>
        <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar, class: 'w-10 h-10 rounded-full mr-4' %>
      <% end %>
      <div>
        <div class="flex items-center mb-1">
          <strong class="text-gray-900"><%= comment.user.username %></strong>
          <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-2"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + " ago" %></span>
        </div>
        <p class="text-gray-800 mb-2"><%= comment.content %></p>
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
          <% if comment.likes.exists?(user: current_user) %>
            <%= button_to  unlike_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'text-sm text-blue-500' do %>
              <%= heroicon "hand-thumb-up", variant: :solid, options: { class: "h-5 w-5" } %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <%= button_to like_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'text-sm text-blue-500' do %>
              <%= heroicon "hand-thumb-up", variant: :outline, options: { class: "h-5 w-5" } %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <span class="text-sm text-gray-500"><%= pluralize(comment.likes.count, 'like') if comment.likes.count > 0 %></span>
          <% if current_user == comment.user %>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), class: 'text-sm text-gray-500' %>
            <%= button_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, remote: true, data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: 'text-sm text-red-500' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

here in _comment.html.erb we have turbo_frame_tag dom_id(comment), which renders each comment with a unique ID, so we can target it later.
When we click on edit button in above code, turbo will look for another turbo frame with same comment ID as of the frame where we are clicking on Edit button. So in my edit.html.erb file we have same turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@comment)
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@comment) do %>
  <div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto px-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-4">
    <h2 class="text-l font-semibold mb-4">Edit Comment</h2>
    <%= form_with(model: [@post, @comment], local: true, html: { class: "bg-white rounded-lg" }) do |form| %>
      <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation" class="mb-4 bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative">
          <ul>
            <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <%= form.label :content, class: "block text-gray-700 font-semibold" %>
        <%= form.text_area :content, class: "w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg text-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500", rows: 4 %>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-end space-x-4">
        <%= form.submit "Update Comment", class: "bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

So when we click edit button, _comment.html.erb is replaced by edit.html.erb
When we submit this form, then edit form is replaced by _comment.html.erb again because we are using that partial for showing comments. In this way, we can handle inline comment editing without any page refresh or JS.
